# Using the gcc (GNU C) compiler with C99 under Windows (from CLion)

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, clion, blas

I am currently programming in the C language on CLion from JetBrains from a Windows computer.
I would like to use the gcc (GNU C) compiler in order to access external libraries, like BLAS.

At this point, in order to launch the `hello.c` program for instance, I need to go the `CMakeLists.txt` file and write this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(ProjectName C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(ProjectName hello.c)
```

To compile `hello.c` from gcc, I would need to enter `cc hello.c` in the gcc terminal. As CLion has no compilation problem using `CMakeLists.txt`, so far, so good.

Now, I want to use the `dgemv_` function for matrix multiplication. I got the `dgmev.f` Fortran file. To execute my program, I need to use the `BLAS` librairy, and write `cc hello.c -lblas` in gcc. However, **I have no idea how to link my Fortran librairy program with my C program without gcc** (which I haven't).

Thus, I would like to know **how to use the gcc compiler in CLion for C99 under Windows** (maybe with a Makefile script ?), or, if it's not possible, **how to use this Fortran librairy program without gcc**.

Here you have [the complete CLion project folder on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I2xLZPmadu8lJ1LpPWkO54chfk7ZPFbq?usp=sharing) containing all the scripts I wrote about above.

Comment: If CLion can build the program, then you already have GCC installed.

Comment: Good news then, how can I access the gcc terminal, if there is one ? Meaning, where should I write "cc hello.c" ?

Comment: If you use CMake, you don't enter build commands like "cc hello.c", CMake does this for you. Probably you should follow some introductory tutorial to learn how to use CMake with CLion. -- While you're at learning, also read the documentation of CMake to see how to add a library to your CMakeLists.txt.